# Exit Code in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a log file and at the end of my script I need to look through the log file. If it contains the words "ERROR: or WARNING:" I need the script to shoot an exit code of 0. If it does not contain those words I need the script to shoot out an exit code of 1. Basically, if it finds those words I need it to be true and if not I need it to be false. This log will be looked at from an ESP Scheduler so I need my script to shoot out a fail or success code to ESP.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$Exit = Get-Content 'H:\REPO\ADNEW\AlertLog.txt'
if ($Exit -cmatch "ERROR:") {exit 1}
if ($Exit -cmatch "WARNING:") {exit 1}
ifelse ($Exit -cnotmatch "WARNING:", "ERROR:") {exit 0}

echo $LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your current code ? What's the output and what's the error (if any) ? Please edit your question and add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Get-Content` without the `-Raw` switch, you're getting back a collection of `string` (there is an edge-case where a single return is a `scalar` instead of an `array`).  When you use the comparison operators against a collection, it acts as a *filter* and does not return a boolean value.  Putting this knowledge together, you can do something like this:

```
$log = Get-Content -Path H:\AlertLog.txt -Raw

if ($log -cmatch '(?m)(ERROR|WARNING):') {
    1
    exit 1
}
0
exit 0
```

This utilizes the regex multi-line matching option and ensures `$log` is a single string instead of a collection by using the `Raw` switch.  Additionally, it echoes the exitcode to the stdout stream before exiting the process with that code.

Comment: PowerShell operators act as enumerators, and empty/non-empty results are interpreted as false or true respectively in boolean contexts, so whether the file is read as a single string or an array of lines shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You're correct, in this case, but it's important to know what's happening so that they don't think "oh, I have a match" when it could be "oh, I have multiple matches."  It's confusing for people new to the language and conditionals being truthy doesn't assist in that knowledge gap.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Perfect!, Thank you